# how to remove directories structures not accessed since a specific date?

Tags: windows, powershell, file

how to remove directories structures not accessed since a specific date ?

it might look like something :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -filter IDENTIFY_DIRECTRORY | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | IDENTIFYTHELASTACCCESSTIME | Remove-Item -Force
```

IDENTIFY_DIRECTORY : I guess it is : `-Directory` parameter to Get-ChildItem command *(select directories only not files)*

IDENTIFYTHELASTACCCESSTIME : here I mean check if directory or sub-path/file has been accessed/read since a date I would set from a variable

Final goal of that is to purge useless files from a fileserver to free a maximum of space.
I already did :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -filter *.log | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

maybe workaround

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\" $_.LastAcessTime -Recurse -Directory -Force -<somemorecommandlineparameters> ......
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that `CreationTime` and access time are two different things. What do you mean by `IDENTIFY_DIRECTORY : I guess it is : -Directory`?

Comment: I really mean here access_date or accesstime.

Comment: This bit `| Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer` makes no sense if you want to find directories. For instance, try something like `Get-ChildItem $env:USERPROFILE -Directory | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }` and you might see what I mean. Also, make sure Access Time is something that actually gets updated on access - this isn't always the case.

Comment: ok then something like `Get-Children -Directory -recurse | where-object { $_.lastaccesstime -lt ((get-date).adddays( variablename )) } | select fullname, lastaccesstime, lastwritetime` for the listing right ?

Comment: Finally I use some python scripts to manage that issue but it's just a workaround.

Comment: For what it's worth; you nearly had a PS solution here.